# How to get Json's parent element using Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

There is json like the following.

```
{
  {
      "id": 1,
      "child": [
          {
              "id": 4,
              "child": [],
          },
          {
              "id": 2,
              "child": [
                  {
                      "id": 37,
                      "child": [],
                  },
                  {
                      "id": 39,
                      "child": [],
                  }
              ]
          },
          {
              "id": 3,
              "child": [],
          },
      ]
  },
  {
      "id": 120,
      "child": [],
  },
  {
    "id": 121,
    "child": [
        {
            "id": 122,
            "child": [],
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

For example, what would you do if you wanted to get the id of the parent element of an element whose id is 37?
In this case we want to get in a list such as `[1, 2]`.

I thought that we should recursively process as below, but I do not know how to get parent elements when id matches.

```
def get_parent(self, json_tree, target_id):
    for element in json_tree:
        if element['id'] == target_id:
            ????
        else:
            if element['child']:
                self.get_routes_tree(element['child'],
                                     target_id)
```

Comment: Are you sure this is valid json?

Comment: There's no "json" type in Python. json is a text format, once parsed what you get are plain python objects (dicts, lists, strings etc).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers this doesn't convert to any Python type except a string though

Comment: @Farhan.K I beg your pardon ? `json.loads('{"foo": 42, "bar":[1, 2, 3], "wot": 1.66666666666666667}')` => `{u'wot': 1.6666666666666667, u'foo': 42, u'bar': [1, 2, 3]}`. I see a dict, a list, some ints and a float here... It's a conform json parser that supports all the data types defined in json.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I'm not talking generally. I'm talking about the example in the question. Try `json.loads` with the example in the question.

Comment: @Farhan.K AOK sorry I totally misunderstood your comment #oops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the list of nodes used to reach the bottom `id` you could use the following:

```
def get_parent(json_tree, target_id):
    for element in json_tree:
        if element['id'] == target_id:
            return [element['id']]
        else:
            if element['child']:
                check_child = get_parent(element['child'], target_id)
                if check_child:
                    return [element['id']] + check_child
```

This creates a list when the `id` is matched, and then as it is passed back up the loops, adds the `id` for each level to the front of the list.

So, correcting your json to be proper (no trailing commas) and calling the function:

```
js = json.loads('[{"id": 1,"child": [{"id": 4,"child": []},{"id": 2,"child": [{"id": 37,"child": []},{"id": 39,"child": []}]},{"id": 3,"child": []}]},{"id": 120,"child": []},{"id": 121,"child": [{"id": 122,"child": []}]}]')

print(get_parent(js, 37))
```

prints

```
[1, 2, 37]
```

Answer (score 0):

*code.py*:

```
import sys


TREE = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "child": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "child": [],
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "child": [
                    {
                        "id": 37,
                        "child": [],
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 39,
                        "child": [],
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "child": [],
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 120,
        "child": [],
    },
    {
        "id": 121,
        "child": [
            {
                "id": 122,
                "child": [],
            }
        ]
    }
]


def get_chain_ids(tree_dict, target_id, depth=0):
    cur_id = tree_dict["id"]
    if cur_id == target_id:
        yield cur_id
    else:
        yield_cur_id = False
        for child_dict in tree_dict["child"]:
            for child_id in get_chain_ids(child_dict, target_id, depth=depth + 1):
                yield_cur_id = True
                yield child_id
        if yield_cur_id:
            yield cur_id


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))

    for item in TREE:
        print("\nSearching tree (id: {:d})...".format(item["id"]))
        ids = get_chain_ids(item, 37)
        if (ids):
            for item in ids:
                print(item)
```

**Notes**:

- Uses [[Python]: Generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)
- The *json* (`TEXT` *dict*) was incorrect, I had to adjust it (besides formatting)
- `get_chain_ids` takes the tree *root* (`tree_dict`) which is a dictionary, and `target_id` as arguments, and returns a generator yielding all the node ids from `target_id` to the root id
- `depth` is currently not used
- Since `TREE` is a `list` of nodes, I had to iterate over it and pass each element to the function
- **It doesn't handle** cases where a node is malformed (lacks `"id"` or `"child"` keys, or if their values are not as expected)

**Output**:

> ```
> (py35x64_test) E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048865303>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
>
> Searching tree (id: 1)...
> 37
> 2
> 1
>
> Searching tree (id: 120)...
>
> Searching tree (id: 121)...
> ```